# Broken terminal after piping fzf + xargs + less on Kitty + Bash

Tags: terminal, pipe, less, xargs, fzf

I'm trying to combine `fzf` output with a command launched through `xargs` whose output needs to be paginated with `less`.

The simplest example using basic commands is the following:

```
echo test | fzf | xargs echo | less
```

In the example, I use `echo` and the string `test` to make it self-contained.

The whole command allows the selection of the string `test` using `fzf`, then launches the simplest useful command (`echo`) using `xargs`, whose output is expected to be paginated using `less`.

However, when `less` is run, the terminal results "broken" and requires a `reset` to be usable again.

Is there a way to make it working without "breaking" the terminal?

Interestingly, the following variants, where one single pipe is removed, do not cause any problem:

```
echo test | fzf | less
```

```
echo test | xargs echo | less
```

```
echo test | fzf | xargs echo
```

so it seems that it is the combination of the three programs that causes the problem.

--- ADDEDUM ---

After some more tests, I found that the problem arises when the command is run under Kitty as terminal emulator and Bash as shell.

Tried under Kitty + Zsh -> it works.
Tried under xterm + Bash -> it works.

I would now mark this question as too narrow scope to be interesting!
I refined the title to reflect this specificity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Kitty + fzf (on macOS) and solved it by prefixing the fzf command line to set the TERM environment variable to "xterm", for example this solves the issue for me in zsh at least:

```
TERM=xterm $(echo test | fzf | xargs echo | less)
```

I'm not sure why it works, but every so often something breaks kitty and adding a `TERM=xterm` often seems to help, which is odd because `echo $TERM` returns "xterm" for me in a new shell anyway.